# JPA native query and plpgsql returning type

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I've created a postgresql function, which returns custom row type, created like this:

```
create type typename as ( 
   a bigint,
   b bigint
);
```

In function I've declared return variable `result typename%rowtype;`. I've tested this function in pg_admin, it works correct, result returns correct.

I've created class `typename` in java, with Long variables 'a' and 'b'.(without any annotation, don't know which one I need to use)

I've called the function in interface which extends JpaRepository:

```
@Query(value = "select func_name()", nativeQuery = true)
typename func_call();
```

And I've got an exception: MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

Something wrong with returning type, because I've tried to return bigint(Long) value and it works correct.

So, how can I get custom returning type in JPA?

---

Comment: You need to implement a type handler for Hibernate to work with your custom type. Here is an article with an example https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/20/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Comment: Additionally you should know for that implementation calling `getObject` on the ResultSet will return you a org.postgresql.util.PGobject, which contains the value as a string, so you might as well just use `getString`.